# How to use a differente theme for a specific page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a default theme for my app. I customize this theme using Style file in Android. But I'm creating a login page that I want use other theme just for it. How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101742/how-to-change-xamarin-forms-theme-programmatically-at-runtime).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do that, because Android theme can be applied to an activity in Android, but Xamarin.Forms run "within" a single activity, so you would have to do the styling either in Xamarin.Forms. Check out [this post on Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84863/changing-the-platform-specific-theme-at-runtime-for-android) where the developer was able to change the theme at runtime, which however restarted the activity and in turn also his Xamarin.Forms app.

Answer (score 0):

If your Xamarin Forms app is only using one activity, then this is quite straightforward. This solution is for Lollipop and versions after. You can do this using platform specific Android code:

```
public class StatusBarStyleManager : IStatusBarStyleManager
{
    public void SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color color)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var currentWindow = GetCurrentWindow();
                currentWindow.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
                currentWindow.SetStatusBarColor(color);
            });
        }
    }

    Window GetCurrentWindow()
    {
        //Note this is a nuget package for retrieving the activity.
        var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;

        // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

        // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

        return window;
    }
}
```

Then just use this implementation in your pages to set their specific status bar colors when they appear.

Inspired by this article when I needed this in my own projects:
https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/08/20/dynamically-changing-the-status-bar-appearance-in-xamarin-forms/